# Splitting dataset into groups in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset where individuals belong to no group, one group, or more than one group. It looks like this

```
  resp_id     G1     G2      G3       G4       G5      G6
    1         0      1        1        0       0        1
    2         1      1        0        1       0        0
    3         0      0        0        0       0        0
    4         0      1        0        0       0        0
    5         0      1        0        0       0        0
```

and so on for about 400 rows. Here, '1' signifies groups membership and '0' means they aren't a part of the group. I want to assign individuals to groups such that:

1. All individuals are in at most 1 group
2. I have 6 approximately similar-sized groups (~46 people per group. Total number of people who are a part of at least 1 group is 278.)

Is there a way I can do this in R?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the sample data had to do with the question.

Comment: "1" signifies group membership. At the end, I want each row (not counting rest_id) to contain only one "1". I want to prioritise group membership such that each person is a part of only one group, and each group (G1 to G6) has around 46 members

Comment: so just divide your participants (400) into 6 groups (around 66/67 id's for each group). From the first group, draw 46 members that enter G1, the rest gets 0. From the second group, draw 46 that enter G2, and so on until G6.

Comment: All people are not a part of all groups, and group membership is not even. If I were to do this, I would end up with way less people in the last group. Even if I prioritise groups by membership count, the group that starts off largest would end up with the least number of people

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this?

```
#persons
id = 1:400
# draw 6 groups of 46 unique persons
L <- lapply(split(id, cut(id, 6)), sample, 47, replace = FALSE)
names(L) <- paste0("G", 1:6)
L <- lapply(L, as.data.table)
# bind to a data.table
DT <- rbindlist(L, id = "group", use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
# final approach
final <- data.table(id = id)
final[DT, group := i.group, on = .(id = V1)]

answer <- dcast(final, id ~ group, value.var = "id", fun.aggregate = length)

colSums(answer)
# id       NA    G1    G2    G3    G4    G5    G6 
# 80200   118    47    47    47    47    47    47 

head(answer, 20)
#    id NA G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6
# 1:  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 2:  2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 3:  3  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 4:  4  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 5:  5  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 6:  6  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 7:  7  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 8:  8  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 9:  9  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#10: 10  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#11: 11  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#12: 12  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#13: 13  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#14: 14  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#15: 15  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#16: 16  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#17: 17  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#18: 18  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#19: 19  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#20: 20  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```